# java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method DoublyLinkedList.isEmpty()Z is abstract?

Tags: java, list, doubly-linked-list

My toString() method at the bottom is giving me the above error when trying to test for an empty DoublyLinkedList in my main method also at the bottom. My intuition tells me that this may be caused by the List interface that I'm implementing since the word "List" is underlined in red reading "The type List is already defined" and the isEmpty() method is pulled from that interface. Not entirely sure though. Hope this isn't a burden to anyone. Thanks in advance.

```
public class DoublyLinkedList<T> implements List<T> {

  /**
   * Node is a pair containing a data field and a pointers to
   * the previous and next nodes in the list.
   */
  class Node {
    T data;
    Node next, prev;

    Node(T data) {
      this(data, null, null);
    }

    Node(T data, Node prev, Node next) {
      this.data = data;
      this.prev = prev;
      this.next = next;
    }
  }

  Node head;  // always points to the headnode for this list
  int n;      // the number of nodes in this list, initially 0

  /**
   * Creates the empty list. 
   */
  public DoublyLinkedList() {
    // TODO: Create the headnode.
    // Note that the prev and next fields in the headnode should 
    // point back to the headnode.
      Node head = new Node(null);
      head.prev=head;
      head.next=head;

  }

  public String toString() {
      System.out.println("meeee");
    if (this.isEmpty())
      return "()";    
    Iterator<T> it = iterator();
    StringBuilder ans = new StringBuilder("(").append(it.next());
    while (it.hasNext())
      ans.append(" ").append(it.next());
    return ans.append(")").toString();
  }

 public static void main(String... args) {
    DoublyLinkedList<Integer> xs = new DoublyLinkedList<>();
    System.out.println(xs.toString());
}

interface List<T> extends Iterable<T> {
  void add(T x);  // simple add
  T remove(int i);
  T get(int i);
  boolean contains(T x);
  int size();
  default boolean isEmpty() {
    return size() == 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Remove the `java.util.List` import.

Comment: hmmm I don't believe it was even in my code to begin with